# Spring Session not using custom RedisTemplate bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, redis, spring-session

Trying to use a RedisTemplate bean with GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer, but while debugging I noticed Spring Session uses a different RedisTemplate instance.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisHttpSessionConfig extends 
    AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
```

When running this, Spring Session seems to use the default JdkSerializationRedisSerializer for hashValues, instead of the desired GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.

Removing `extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer` seems to make Spring use the correct RedisTempplate bean, but then Spring Session isn't wired at all.

Using Spring Session 1.3.3, and spring-boot-starter-data
-redis 1.5.13.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure and register a RedisTemplate bean named `sessionRedisTemplate`. This will override the default RedisTemplate instance provided by `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration`.

You should configure it like:

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> sessionRedisTemplate() {
    final RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you just need to override default RedisSerializer for spring session like this

```
@Configuration public class RedisConfig {

@Bean(name="springSessionDefaultRedisSerializer")
public RedisSerializer serializer() {
    return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
}
```